# Get section name and other attribute from a config file using git-config

Tags: bash, git, git-config

.gitmodules gets updated by different script, now I am trying to find the name and path of the submodule whose URL has changed, below code works, but there should be a better way?

```
#Check if .gitmodules file has changed.
file_changed=$(git diff --name-only HEAD .gitmodules)
if [[ $file_changed = '.gitmodules' ]]; then
   # get all the URLs which were changed.
   urls=($(git diff HEAD .gitmodules | grep "^+\s*url" | cut -d' ' -f3))
   for url in "${urls[@]}"; do
      echo "$url changed"
      submod_string=$(git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp submodule.*.url | grep $url | cut -d' ' -f1)
      submod_name=$(echo ${submod_string} | cut -d. -f2)
      submod_path=$(git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp --path submodule.${submod_name}.path | cut -d' ' -f2)
   done
fi
```

.gitmodules file looks as below, say if bbb's url has changed, then I need to get its name `bbb` and path `BBB`

```
$ cat .gitmodules
[submodule "aaa"]
    path = AAA
    url = https://blah.com/test/3a
[submodule "bbb"]
    path = BBB
    url = https://blah.com/test/3b
[submodule "ccc"]
    path = CCC
    url = https://blah.com/test/3c
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by detecting updates to .gitmodules? I think you are trying to recreate the functionality of `git submodule sync`

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon If .gitmodules file is updated with wrong URL, `git submodule sync` is not failing (it's not doing  a sync as its already synced with old url, just that URL got updated now), so I am thinking to remove bbb's enty in `.gitconfig`, then `rm -rf BBB`, then do `git submodule sync` to make it fail if URL is wrong, if there is any better way to do this it will be great, thanks.

Comment: *please `.gitconfig` as `.git/config` in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a [`git submodule foreach`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt) loop.

It does have:

- `$name` set to the name
- `$sm_path` set to the path

That would avoid grepping the `.gitmodules` itself.